# input password webchat

Tags: botframework, web-chat

I have a problem with input password in webchat.I used Sample - Customize Web Chat with Password Input Activity for password input card when I enter wrong password it show a message like wrong password please try again but when i enter password out of form i need to show another message.

I used this code.

```
if (card.activity.type === 'message') {
        if (
          card.activity.from.role === 'bot' &&
          (card.activity.text === getLoginMessage(this.props.language) ||
            card.activity.text === getLoginRetryMessage(this.props.language))
        ) {
          let message = card.activity.text;
          if (!this.hasSubmittedPassword && (card.activity.text === getLoginRetryMessage(this.props.language))) {
            message = "Please fill the form and click enter in order to complete your request.";
          }
          return children => (
            <ConnectedPasswordInputActivity
              promptMessage={message}
              passwordPlaceholder={this.props.literals.password}
              language={this.props.language}
              handlePasswordSubmit={this.handlePasswordSubmit}
            >
              {next(card)(children)}
            </ConnectedPasswordInputActivity>
          );
        }
```

[Refer to the image please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMM0g.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to know for certain as there is a lot of hidden code you are referencing, however I suspect the issue is tied to your `hasSubmittedPassword` function and your check against it.

You are matching on

1. A message
2. From a bot
3. Where the text equals either the `getLoginMessage` or `getLoginRetryMessage` return value

These are passing your check (based on the attached image).

You then check against `hasSubmittedPassword` which (apparently) is passing and then check a second time on `getLoginRetryMessage` (???). This second check is unnecessary as you wouldn't be in this `if` statement if the first check (`card.activity.text = this.getLoginRetryMessage(this.props.language)` hadn't succeeded.

This can be simplified to:

```js
if (!this.hasSubmittedPassword) {
    message = "Please fill the form and click enter in order to complete your request.";
}
```

That being said, your use of `if(!this.hasSubmittedPassword) {...}` is only checking if there is a returned value or not. This function may or may not be returning the correct value, but your check doesn't care. It only wants to know *IF* there is a value. If your logic is setup to always return something (i.e. true, false, yes, no, try again), then it will always pass.

From what I can see, if your first three checks pass, then you will always get the secondary message.

Hope of help!

Comment: hello, thank you for your answer. I just want to show one specific message when i enter password out of inputPassword field and another when i enter password on inputPassword field but it's incorrect and i want to show a message like wrong password please try again.